# select the hovered element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using a plugin for getting a popover on hovering on a single element [here](http://effinroot.eiremedia.netdna-cdn.com/repo/plugins/effects-ui/popover/index.html#usage_modifying_content)

```
    $('td.more-info').popover({
        trigger: 'hover',
        title: "More Details",
        content: $(this).attr('pop-content'),
        position: "bottom",
        classes: "popover-class"
    });
```

from the above code i want to make an attribute ( pop-content ) that i will put the content for the popover content 
, put using $(this) doesn't target the (td.more-info) how can i target it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
 content: function(){return $(this).attr('pop-content')},
```